# Email verification links works in Chrome but not Safari or Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, reactjs, react-router

I have an application that sends users a verification email. From here, the user must click an email verification link which looks like this:  http://example.com/#/verify/5133110562f8cb5171ff0033. Instead of hitting this link, Safari and Firefox both automatically redirect to http://example.com/. This prevents the user from signing up. I've checked our backend, and the route that verifies a user is never being hit, meaning that this link is never actually hit in Firefox or Safari. Any ideas on why this would work in Chrome but not the other two?

EDIT
I initially thought this problem was strictly due to the browser, but I actually think it is likely coming from react-router, which I am using to handle the routes in my ReactJS application.

Comment: I think you should file an issue with RR.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

The link I have described starts with

```
"http://"
```

rather than

```
"http://www"
```

While Chrome will still understand that this URL still describes a relative URL of example.com, Firefox and Safari will simply redirect you to the homepage. Adding a "www" fixes the problem.