# Safari and Laravel - Mail Verification

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, session, safari

**Background Story**

I've been developing a Laravel application for about a month now. During the development I've only used google chrome for testing the application. The project makes use of Laravels mustverify to verify the users email. This works flawless in google chrome, however, when I switched to my MacBook, using safari, things got ugly.

**The Problem**

When I get the mail from the application to my mail-client, I usually just click the link "Verify Email Address" shown below. However, this just does not work in Safari. Normally I get sent to the user-panel as a verified user (in google chrome), but in Safari, I get redirected to the login-page (not verified or "logged in"), as of if the session does not exist in the safari browser.

[image: Image of the verification email]

**So what have I tried?**

- Try another browser on my Mac: Downloaded google chrome, works just fine.
- Spent a few hours on reading the documentation of the Auth process of Laravel.

I also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847310/email-verification-links-works-in-chrome-but-not-safari-or-firefox) that says that Safari requires a "www." in front of the url to make it understand. But how would I achieve this in a localhost?

So now I'm reaching out to you for tips, thoughts or ideas. I will list some information below that might be relevant:

- PHP version: 7.3.24
- Laravel Version: 8.20.1
- Software Stack: LEMP & LAMP (running both on different machines to test)
- Safari Version: 14.0.2

Comment: You need to be logged in to verify your email.

Comment: @miken32 Yeah I understand that part. But how come the users are logged in when the click the link in chrome, but not when they click it in Safari? This must have something to do with Safari and it's way of managing cookies right? A user Is automatically logged in as fast as the registration process is done, at least that's how I understand it.

Comment: That depends on how long your sessions last, privacy settings on the browser, etc. Users are not logged in when they click the link in Chrome. They were already logged in before they clicked the link.

Comment: @miken32 Okey, thanks for your input! How would you approach this problem? Make a email verification system that does not require login seems to be the only way to go if I want my users to be able to use Safari I suppose?

Comment: Why can't users log in on Safari?

Comment: @miken32 That's a good question. After some testing with different browsers and different versions of Safari,its only the lastest version of Safari (the security update), that fails this process. Seems like the problem is not caused by my application, but rather by Safari it-self. I'll keep looking for the cause of this, and post it as an answer if I found it. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that Safari did not trust the links that mailtrap provided me with. When switching to a normal mail client, everything works fine.

Comment: Same for yopmail, thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `session.same_site` config to use `none` or `null`

don't forget to use `lax` or `strict` in production

probably a Safari Bug... but this is how I fixed it...

I've provided an answer here also...

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-8-email-verification-not-working-with-different-browsers